# Collision detection for Tiny Wings-esque Windows Phone game?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, c#-4.0, collision-detection

I'm currently working on a Windows Phone game similar to [Tiny Wings](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/tiny-wings/id417817520?mt=8) and I've been having trouble with collision detection between the player's character and the hills. I've been looking into a few different ways to do this including the Farseer Physics engine and a [Silverlight tutorial](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/XNA-for-Silverlight-developers-Part-7-Collision-detection.aspx)

Player's character initialization

```
lander = new Lander(new Vector2(graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth / 4, 100));
```

LoadContent

```
 protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        // Create a new SpriteBatch, which can be used to draw textures.
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
        primitiveBatch = new PrimitiveBatch(GraphicsDevice);

        // Load textures
        landerTexture = this.Content.Load<Texture2D>(".\\Sprites\\boysmall");

        // Initialize lander based on texture
        lander.Width = landerTexture.Width;
        lander.Height = landerTexture.Height;

        // Load the parallaxing background
        bgLayer1.Initialize(Content, "hillsbackground", GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width, -2, 150);
        bgLayer2.Initialize(Content, "hillsbackground2", GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width, -3, 220);

        // Load hills
        string[] hillsArray = new string[2]{"textured","hillsmooth"};
        mainHill.Initialize(Content, hillsArray, GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width, -4);

        // Load Sky
        mainBackground.Initialize(Content, "mainbackground", GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width, -1, 0);
    }
```

I understand that fundamentally, collision detection looks for intersection points between two rectangles, and have done that for the "lander", but don't know how I can do it for the hills and how to make it slide down smoothly? let me know if you need any additional code, thanks for your help!

Rectangle attempt for Lander

```
 public Rectangle GetScreenRectangle()
    {
        // calculate the rectangle from the current location
        // and the current source rectangle
        var rectangle = new Rectangle(
            (int)graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth / 4,
            (int)100,
            lander.Width,
            lander.Height);

        return rectangle;
    }
```

Hills Code

```
class MainHill
{
    // The image representing the parallaxing background
    Texture2D texture;

    // An array of positions of the parallaxing background
    //Vector2[] positions;

    // The speed which the background is moving
    int speed;

    // Object array holding position and texture of each live texture
    object[,] positionsArray = new object[2, 2];

    public void Initialize(ContentManager content, Array hillsArray, int screenWidth, int speed)
    {


        // Load the background texture we will be using
        //texture = content.Load<Texture2D>("textured");

        // Set the speed of the background
        this.speed = speed;

        // If we divide the screen with the texture width then we can determine the number of tiles need.
        // We add 1 to it so that we won't have a gap in the tiling
        //positions = new Vector2[screenWidth / texture.Width + 2];
        texture = content.Load<Texture2D>("textured");

        // Set the initial positions of the parallaxing background
        for (int i = 0; i < screenWidth / texture.Width + 2; i++)
        {
            //Pull out random texture
            Random random = new Random();
            string[] randomHill = new string[2];
            randomHill[0] = "textured";
            randomHill[1] = "hillsmooth";
            string currentString = randomHill[(int)(random.Next(0, 2))];
            texture = content.Load<Texture2D>(currentString);

            // We need the tiles to be side by side to create a tiling effect
            positionsArray[i,0] = new Vector2(i * texture.Width, 290);
            positionsArray[i, 1] = texture;
        }
    }

    public void Update(ContentManager content)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("=========================");
        // Update the positions of the background
        for (int i = 0; i < positionsArray.GetLength(0); i++)
        {               
            Vector2 current_position = (Vector2)positionsArray[i, 0];
            // Update the position of the screen by adding the speed
            current_position.X += speed;

            // Check the texture is out of view then put that texture at the end of the screen
            if (current_position.X <= -texture.Width)
            {
                // Figure out a possibly new texture if it's out of view
                Random random = new Random();
                string[] newHill = new string[2];
                newHill[0] = "textured";
                newHill[1] = "hillsmooth";
                string currentString = newHill[(int)(random.Next(0, 2))];
                texture = content.Load<Texture2D>(currentString);
                Color[] textureData = new Color[texture.Width * texture.Height];
                texture.GetData(textureData);

                current_position.X = texture.Width * (positionsArray.GetLength(0) - 1);
                positionsArray[i, 1] = texture;
            }

            positionsArray[i, 0] = current_position;

        }

    }


    public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch, ContentManager content)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < positionsArray.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            Vector2 current_position = (Vector2)positionsArray[i, 0];
            //Random random = new Random();
            //string[] hillsArray = new string[2];
            //hillsArray[0] = "textured";
            //hillsArray[1] = "hillsmooth";
            //string currentString = hillsArray[(int)(random.Next(0,2))];
            //texture = content.Load<Texture2D>(currentString);
            texture = (Texture2D)positionsArray[i, 1];
            spriteBatch.Draw(texture, current_position, Color.White);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: not sure how with sprites.  however, if the mountain was a texture-filled line-list, then each segment would have a vector normal that can be used to orient your lander on.  collision detection is then segment overlap with bounding rect plus fluff.